# Parsing varied URLs and adding .active class to #navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url, navigation

I need a jQuery (or JavaScript) that will parse a page’s current URL and apply a css class (.active) to the site’s navigation (#nav tabs), in order to highlight the current active section of the site. The site produces a variety of URLs, many of which will result in the same #nav link being made active.

Example URL 1:  mycompany.com/Page.asp?name=foo

There are about a dozen “named” .asp pages that fall under 3 nav tabs (name=foo, name=boo, name=poo, name=woo, name=zoo, where foo and woo are active under #nav1, boo and poo are active under #nav2, zoo is active under #nav3, etc…)

Example URL 2:  mycompany.com/fooapage.aspx?vwc=2345678…

There are several server-generated URLs that all start with the same filename “fooapage.asp, foobpage.asp, foocpage.asp, foodpage.asp,” where all the “foo…” pages will activate the same #nav tab.

Example URL 3:  mycompany.com/bar.asp

There are also several pages that are unique .asp filenames (“a.asp, b.asp, c.asp, d.asp…”) which will need to point to different #nav tabs.

So what I need is a script that will parse out my url and add the .active class to the correct #nav tab as needed. Sadly, I’m a javascript noob, and am not sure how to best do this.

```
if name=foo then #nav1.active
if name=poo then #nav2.active
if name=woo then #nav3.active
if name=zoo then #nav1.active
et cetera…

if filename(starts with)foo then #nav4.active

if filename==a.asp then #nav5.active
if filename==b.asp then #nav5.active
if filename==c.asp then #nav6.active
if filename==x.asp then #nav6.active
if filename==y.asp then #nav7.active
if filename==z.asp then #nav7.active
et cetera…
```

I’ve been looking at scripts & functions that parse out URLs, and if/then statements, but i’m not sure quite how to put them all together in the correct way. Any advice, insight, or assistance would be very much appreciated. Thank you all in advance for any time or consideration you give this problem.

Comment: You should rather consider doing this straight from aspx.

Comment: I would absolutely do this in aspx if I could. I don't have access to it though, hence my difficulty.